# Create column out of different rows from grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to make a new column that somehow pastes in order the data from cols 2 through 6 (separated by a space I guess) for ONLY non-NAs (there will only be one non-NA entry per column per group.

Here is a dput of the first two groups of my data (grouped by "game.event". The desired column created should have - in each row - the following:

For all game.event rows in group 279310, the new col should return: "NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL"
For all game event rows in group 279315, the new col should return: "Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Out Go/Fly Curl"

One last thing. These two groups have six rows per group and for most part this is the norm but some game.event groups might have 5 I think.

dput:

```
    structure(list(game.event = c("279310", "279310", "279310", "279310", 
    "279310", "279310", "279315", "279315", "279315", "279315", "279315", 
    "279315"), L1 = c("NULL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Fade - Back Shoulder", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), L2 = c(NA, "NULL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Curl", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), R2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "NULL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    "Out", NA, NA), R1 = c(NA, NA, "NULL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Go/Fly", 
    NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "NULL", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "Curl")), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame"))
```

dplyr answer desired but will accept anything that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `group_split` by 'game.event', loop over the `list` with `map`, `unlist` the columns other than the 'game.event', remove the `NA`s (`na.omit`) and `paste` (`str_c` - from stringr) to summarize in a `tibble`, rbind the `list` elements with `_dfr` in `map`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
   group_split(game.event) %>%
   map_dfr(~ tibble(game.event = first(.x$game.event),
      new = str_c(na.omit(unlist(.x[-1])), collapse= " ")))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  game.event new                                      
  <chr>      <chr>                                    
1 279310     NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
2 279315     Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Out Go/Fly Curl
```

---

or another option is using `nest_by` and `transmute` by `unlist`ing the 'data' column and `paste`ing the non-NA elements

```
df %>% 
   nest_by(game.event) %>%
   transmute(new = str_c(na.omit(unlist(data)), collapse=" ")) %>% 
   ungroup
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  game.event new                                      
  <chr>      <chr>                                    
1 279310     NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
2 279315     Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Out Go/Fly Curl
```

#### Update

If we want to add a placeholder for columns that have only `NA`s, we could replace one of the elements to character `"NA"` and thus it won't be removed with `na.omit`

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(game.event) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) c("NA", .[-1]) else .)) %>% 
    nest() %>%
    transmute(new = str_c(na.omit(unlist(data)), collapse=" ")) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  game.event new                   
  <chr>      <chr>                 
1 2793135    Curl Curl NA Curl NULL
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(game.event = c("2793135", "2793135", "2793135", "2793135", "2793135", "2793135"), L1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Curl", NA, NA), L2 = c(NA, NA, "Curl", NA, NA, NA), R2 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_ ), R1 = c("Curl", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "NULL")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Fantastic! I am finding now that I ran this on all data another issue I need to deal with. There are some columns with all NA in each of the 6 rows and I need to make some sort of placeholder so that I have the same amount of strings (5) in the created column. (I will be wanting to separate those columns after all of this so they need to be lined up correctly)

Comment: Here is a dput of what I mean:    structure(list(game.event = c("2793135", "2793135", "2793135", 
"2793135", "2793135", "2793135"), L1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Curl", 
NA, NA), L2 = c(NA, NA, "Curl", NA, NA, NA), R2 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), R1 = c("Curl", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "NULL")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

Comment: @JeffHenderson would that row be removed i.e. filtered before or should be a single NA

Comment: @JeffHenderson Do you want something like in the update

Comment: If I understand you correctly I think NA would work. So for instance the above dput should return a col with "Curl Curl NA Curl NULL"

Comment: @JeffHenderson I would consider replacing `NA` with some other value as we do `na.omit` at the end.  In the. update, I showed `"Bad"` or may also change it to character `"NA"` instead as it doesn't matter in your string

Comment: @JeffHenderson I updatd the post.  I hope this works for you

Comment: Yeah bad is fine instead of NA. But for the last dput I put in comment, it didn't input "bad" where it should be - it's not in it at all

Comment: @JeffHenderson Because I changed `Bad` to `"NA"` based on your comment

Comment: You can change this line to `c("NA", .[-1])` to `c("Bad", .[-1])` in the code

Comment: I ran it with bad and NA still not getting anything filled in. frustrating.. I see it worked for you by your response.

Comment: @JeffHenderson it is only your dput structure which should be the same for both of us

Comment: OK, I just reran with the dput and it worked but my original data it doesn't ... let me investigate why I am not sure but yeah after copying the df1 you made it worked

Comment: When you say it is not working, what kind of output you are getting now (in the original data)

Comment: when I search for the game.event id from ex above I get: "Curl Curl Curl NULL"

Comment: @JeffHenderson have you assigned the output to any object i.e. `out <- df1 %>% ..`

Comment: @JeffHenderson if you find a specific game.event having that info, just subset that `game.event` and get the `dput`.  there may be some other info

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not quite following. You've been so helpful and I feel so close!! ha. I did a search in the original data and "bad" isn't found anywhere either but they are both tibbles and I just don't understand why it would work with the dput but not original...

Comment: I undestand the issue

Comment: @JeffHenderson The issue was that I used `mutate` at the beginning to only change those columns having all NA to first element "NA", bu this was done without grouping.  We need this with grouping

Comment: BINGO! we forgot the grouping! This worked! thanks so much. You are a wizard's wizard.

Answer (score 1):

You can `pivot_longer` to get all the values in one column, then drop NAs.

Then group by `game.event`, and create the space-separated string of non-NA values, and join to the original `df`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  left_join(by = "game.event",
    df %>% 
    pivot_longer(-game.event) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
    group_by(game.event) %>% 
    summarise(values = paste(value, collapse = " "))
)

# A tibble: 12 x 7
   game.event L1                   L2    R2    R1     B     values                                   
   <chr>      <chr>                <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                    
 1 279310     NULL                 NA    NA    NA     NA    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
 2 279310     NA                   NULL  NA    NA     NA    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
 3 279310     NA                   NA    NA    NULL   NA    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
 4 279310     NA                   NA    NULL  NA     NA    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
 5 279310     NA                   NA    NA    NA     NULL  NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
 6 279310     NA                   NA    NA    NA     NA    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
 7 279315     Fade - Back Shoulder NA    NA    NA     NA    Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Go/Fly Out Curl
 8 279315     NA                   Curl  NA    NA     NA    Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Go/Fly Out Curl
 9 279315     NA                   NA    NA    Go/Fly NA    Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Go/Fly Out Curl
10 279315     NA                   NA    Out   NA     NA    Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Go/Fly Out Curl
11 279315     NA                   NA    NA    NA     NA    Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Go/Fly Out Curl
12 279315     NA                   NA    NA    NA     Curl  Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Go/Fly Out Curl
```

Note: If you don't immediately need the values in the new column as a space-separated list, you can keep them stored as a list instead of a pasted, space-separated string.  For this, use `summarise(values = list(value))`

Answer (score 1):

You can `unlist` `cur_data()` values, drop `NA` and  paste the output for each `game.event`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(game.event) %>%
  summarise(new = paste(na.omit(unlist(cur_data())), collapse = ' '))

#  game.event new                                      
#  <chr>      <chr>                                    
#1 279310     NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL                 
#2 279315     Fade - Back Shoulder Curl Out Go/Fly Curl
```

If you want to keep the remaining rows and columns as it is and just want to add a new column use `mutate` instead of `summarise`.